Why did the Babylonians choose to add the 13th lunar month every 3, 6, 8, 11, 14, 17, and 19 years, for a 19-year cycle?
Why did the Babylonians choose those 7 years in which to add the extra month? Why not different years? If the answer is not known, what are the closest hypotheses or reasons?

Seminal book: John M. Steele: Calendars and Years: Astronomy and Time in the Ancient Near East, Oxford: Oxbow Books, 2007.

Have you looked at the wikipedia article for Metonic cycle?

@justCal where does it say anything about those 7 days being picked specifically?

There is only one way to organize the insertion of the extra months! They have to be inserted in a cycle after 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3 years respectively. The start of the cycle is arbitrary—depending on where you put it there are 19 ways to describe the inserted months, but they all amount to the same thing, just offset by a constant modulo 19.

@GarethRees, you can also use 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3 if you don't mind extra slippage.

@Mark I'm assuming that the requirements are (i) 12 or 13 months in each year (ii) the start of the year is kept close to some astronomical event such as the spring equinox.

Would that not be better asked somewhere dealing with astrology, astronomy or horology?

Because 19 Divided by 7 is 2.7
To match up the solar and lunar calendars, you need to add 7 months every 19 years. Since 19 / 7 is 2.7, the most straightforward way to add those months is every 2 or 3 years, with more 3 year periods than 2s.
Consistency
The lunar month doesn't quite fit into the solar year - 12 lunar months are roughly 354 days, 11 days short of the solar year. This discrepancy grows over time, until after 19 years it has reach 207 days, almost exactly 7 lunar months.
So you need to add 7 lunar months over 19 years, or the lunar and solar year will drift apart. If you don't, you'll be in one year for the lunar calendar and other for the solar calendar, and that seems really inconvenient.
You could add those 7 months all at the end; just do normal lunar months until 19 years have passed, and then do an extra half year of bonus months to line the two systems up, but that also turns out to be inconvenient.
If Month A is a winter month, and over time the lunar calendar diverges from the solar calendar, Month A will drift into a different season! Eventually, Month A will end up as a summer month, and then the extra half year will thrust it back to it's starting place in winter.
This seems less than ideal. Better would be if we spread the months out evenly, so that the months are always in the same season every year.
This leads us back to 19 divided by 7. We need to add a month every 2.7 years. While we could add the extra months evenly, with a bonus month every 32 months, that seems difficult to keep track of. It's probably easier just to add the month at the end of the year.
So we need a spacing of either 2 or 3 years, weighted towards 3 in order to get the 2.7 average over the 19 years. The spacing of 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2 gives just that value.
Thus addition of an extra month in years 3, 6, 8, 11, 14, 17, and 19 is far from random, it is the optimum solution for aligning the lunar and solar calendars and keeping the lunar months in the same season.

A wonderfull answer for a mathematician. Unfortunately, some of the mathematical concepts you are usng have only been invented in the middle ages. And this is History.SE, not Astronomy.SE. Please add sources that give evidence what the Baybylonians thought when they structured their calendar.

@ccprog: since the Babylonian sources documenting how this calendar was designed did not survive, all we can do is to try to reconstruct their arguments. And this is an excellent answer describing such a reconstruction.  Concerning the literature, some sources are mentioned in the comments to the question.

@ccprog: concerning the placement of this answer. Indeed, the history of calendar partially belongs to the history of mathematics and astronomy. However, since calendar affects the life of ALL people, it also belongs to general history in general. Especially the calendar affects the history itself:-)

@ccprog, you don't formal methods to do this computation.  Trial and error works just fine.

The key to understand the metonic cycle is to focus on the intervals between the embolismic years rather than on the position of those years in the cycle.
In any valid succession of metonic cycles, the sequence of intervals between embolismic years repeats the following pattern:
3 - 3 - 2 - 3 - 3 - 3 - 2 - ...
Since any of the 7 intervals can be chosen as the first interval of a metonic cycle, the actual sequence of embolismic years resulting from the application of a particular astronomical rule (such as "The spring equinox must occur before or on day 14 of the first month") can be viewed as a succession of metonic cycles constructed in any of 7 possible modes, where we will consider only modes which begin with a whole interval (whether 3-year or 2-year), i.e. modes in which year 19 is embolismic.
As anyone familiar with music theory has already noticed at this point, the pattern of 3-year and 2-year intervals between embolismic years in metonic cycles is the same as the pattern of whole and half steps (i.e.tones and semitones) between notes in diatonic scales. Therefore we will name each mode of metonic cycles the same as the homologous mode of diatonic scales.
Below, each mode is built from the one above by removing the first interval and appending it at the end.
2 - 3 - 3 - 2 - 3 - 3 - 3 -   Locrian
  2   5   8  10  13  16  19

    3 - 3 - 2 - 3 - 3 - 3 - 2 -   Ionian (major) - Traditional
      3   6   8  11  14  17  19

        3 - 2 - 3 - 3 - 3 - 2 - 3 -   Dorian - Symmetric
          3   5   8  11  14  16  19

            2 - 3 - 3 - 3 - 2 - 3 - 3 -   Phrygian
              2   5   8  11  13  16  19

                3 - 3 - 3 - 2 - 3 - 3 - 2 -   Lydian 
                  3   6   9  11  14  17  19

                    3 - 3 - 2 - 3 - 3 - 2 - 3 -   Mixolydian
                      3   6   8  11  14  16  19

                        3 - 2 - 3 - 3 - 2 - 3 - 3 -   Aeolian (minor)
                          3   5   8  11  13  16  19

The last embolismic year (i.e. #19) in the Locrian mode and the ones directly below it in the other modes, ending with year #3 in the Aeolian mode, is the year in the cycle in which the 1st, 7th and 13th months (Nisan, Tishrei and Adar II in the Hebrew calendar) start at the earliest date in the solar calendar.

This 19 year cycle is called the Metonic Cycle. It is the most simple math solution to synchronize the tropical (solar) year and the synodic (lunar) month.
